# Java Reducing the window width after running the program without losing the content

Tags: java

I have developed a small desktop application. After running the program I am able to get the window which contains my GUI design. But If I drag the window inside my content is merging, but My requirement here is that I should not loss my content, but it should appear on the same window, any help would be appreciated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you are working with Java Swing or AWT or JavaFX? I saw your picture added in my answer, but don't edit my answer, edit your question and add more detail please. (And I think you added two pictures but they are the same?)

Comment: @FaithReaper I am using Java Swing components, the two images which I have attached is same, but first image is full image after running and the second image is the image of after reducing window width.

Comment: @FaithReaper sorry for the trouble, could you please check the image which I attached?

Comment: Yes I have seen them. OK like I said, you can use ComponentListener. Again, what layout do you use? Some layoutmanagers may handle it for you, like the way described in [another question about MigLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100399/miglayout-resize-components-relatively-to-a-screen-size).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a [`ComponentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to listen for the change of size of a frame. In the listener you have to implement `componentResized` and so on, to determine how it works if the size changes.

You can implement like this:

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JFrame) {
                JFrame frame = (JFrame) (e.getSource());
                int width = frame.getSize().width;
                int height = frame.getSize().height;
                //your logic here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {


        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

But, here in my project someone(developed this app and with no knowledge of any layout manager) set all layout to be `null`, so I must use `setBounds()` to allocate every element. If you use some decent Layout Manager, like `MigLayout`, and set the width of every element to be some percentage of the windows' size, it will handle it for you and you are out of trouble.

You can see [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100399/miglayout-resize-components-relatively-to-a-screen-size). The link is the same as I posted in my comment above.

## EDIT:

I just posted an answer showing how to do it properly without layout manager, but it's takes a lot of time... See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836205/resizing-a-jframe#answer-42113681).

Comment: You're "assuming" the API, the OP has not made it clear what API they are using. it could be Swing or JavaFX or some other GUI framework

Comment: Yes you're right, although it's the most common case. Let's redo the tags added and ask him if it helps.

Comment: No, don't re-do the tags, make the OP make the question clearer, if you screw around with the tags and the OP ends up using something else, you'll just draw the wrath of the users onto the OP

Comment: @FaithReaper I am using here swing components, also I have attached the image , could you please check?